# Why can't I get (most) Chrome command line flags working?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I am running Chrome 51 on Windows 8.1. According to both [this documentation](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and [this source file](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc?view=markup) I should be able to launch Chrome with command line parameters. Yet when I try to - with the exception of `--incognito` - I can't get any to work. Most notably I am trying

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --version

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --window-size=200,200

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

All three of these simply open up a new chrome window with none of the effects I'd expect (the first isn't even supposed to open a window at all).

I have tried, cmd, PowerShell, and launching `cmd.exe` with the `/C` flag.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I think you misread the question. Incognito works exactly as expected, however `--version` just opens a window, `--window-size` just opens a window (not at the requested size), and `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` does not auto open devtools when I open tabs. Do those features work for you?

Comment: I see that does seem to be the case.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT so it's not just me? I [opened an issue on the chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=629279&can=2&q=OS%3DWindows%20command%20line&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)